# ANR Input dispatching timed out on Android 4.4

Tags: java, android, bitmap, decode

I found an error. This is only a part of it:

```
----- pid 6835 at 2014-08-02 05:42:34 -----
Cmd line: lesa.smscallfake

JNI: CheckJNI is off; workarounds are off; pins=0; globals=311

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 SUSPENDED
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4205ae88 self=0x420494d8
| sysTid=6835 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074774356
| state=S schedstat=( 15933846549 2450231013 14646 ) utm=1372 stm=221 core=3
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:~435)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.toString(AbstractStringBuilder.java:645)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:663)
at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:360)
at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:315)
at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:282)
at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:236)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:620)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:634)
at activity.ChiamataEffettuataActivity.getPhotoUri(ChiamataEffettuataActivity.java:127)
at activity.ChiamataEffettuataActivity.onCreate(ChiamataEffettuataActivity.java:64)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"Binder_3" prio=5 tid=15 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x453fe1e0 self=0x78e073c8
| sysTid=7371 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=2034790416
| state=S schedstat=( 5824738 6848644 39 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3
#00 pc 00020710 /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 0002d02b /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
#02 pc 0001d75d /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
#03 pc 0001de97 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand(bool)+18)
#04 pc 0001df3b /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+50)
#05 pc 00021da5 /system/lib/libbinder.so
#06 pc 0000ea5d /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
#07 pc 0004dde5 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
#08 pc 0000e58f /system/lib/libutils.so
#09 pc 0000d258 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#10 pc 0000d3f0 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"AsyncTask #5" prio=5 tid=14 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x454062d0 self=0x7974f218
| sysTid=6933 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=2037708400
| state=S schedstat=( 942497 6026459 11 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x45406428> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=14 (AsyncTask #5)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2017)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"AsyncTask #4" prio=5 tid=13 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4537d608 self=0x719534c0
| sysTid=6855 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1905604888
| state=S schedstat=( 782915 2602712 11 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4537d728> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=13 (AsyncTask #4)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2017)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=12 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4537d478 self=0x719520d8
| sysTid=6854 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1905599792
| state=S schedstat=( 579063 812344 9 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4537d598> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=12 (AsyncTask #3)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2017)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=11 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4537d228 self=0x71951110
| sysTid=6853 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1905595752
| state=S schedstat=( 813803 354219 11 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4537d3c0> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=11 (AsyncTask #2)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2017)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=10 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4537c920 self=0x7193dd18
| sysTid=6852 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1905519696
| state=S schedstat=( 1232138 19486042 17 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4537cab8> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=10 (AsyncTask #1)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2017)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"Binder_2" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x451f8698 self=0x7176fac0
| sysTid=6848 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1903622264
| state=S schedstat=( 10446143 19545574 79 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=3
#00 pc 00020710 /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 0002d02b /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
#02 pc 0001d75d /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
#03 pc 0001de97 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand(bool)+18)
#04 pc 0001df3b /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+50)
#05 pc 00021da5 /system/lib/libbinder.so
#06 pc 0000ea5d /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
#07 pc 0004dde5 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
#08 pc 0000e58f /system/lib/libutils.so
#09 pc 0000d258 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#10 pc 0000d3f0 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_1" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x451f84b8 self=0x7176f008
| sysTid=6847 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1903541152
| state=S schedstat=( 9909064 13567240 78 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3
#00 pc 00020710 /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 0002d02b /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
#02 pc 0001d75d /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
#03 pc 0001de97 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand(bool)+18)
#04 pc 0001df3b /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+50)
#05 pc 00021da5 /system/lib/libbinder.so
#06 pc 0000ea5d /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
#07 pc 0004dde5 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
#08 pc 0000e58f /system/lib/libutils.so
#09 pc 0000d258 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#10 pc 0000d3f0 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 TIMED_WAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x451f3bc8 self=0x7164b358
| sysTid=6845 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1902426032
| state=S schedstat=( 469635 7594584 14 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3
at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1013)
at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:995)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepFor(Daemons.java:248)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForFinalization(Daemons.java:258)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:212)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 WAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x451f3a70 self=0x7164aa28
| sysTid=6844 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1902423680
| state=S schedstat=( 24290203 25912501 258 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=3
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4204f7d8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=5 WAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x451f3908 self=0x7164a180
| sysTid=6843 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1902421464
| state=S schedstat=( 7857403 2493957 162 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4204f700> 
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:130)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=4 VMWAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x451f3818 self=0x71649b20
| sysTid=6842 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1902418136
| state=S schedstat=( 146295056 73149476 1499 ) utm=9 stm=5 core=3
#00 pc 00021a8c /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
#01 pc 0000f04c /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
#02 pc 0000f0ac /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
#03 pc 00076d13 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#04 pc 00057815 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#05 pc 0000d258 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#06 pc 0000d3f0 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
| group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x451f3720 self=0x74066780
| sysTid=6841 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1946576184
| state=R schedstat=( 12132237 6684635 28 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=3
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x451f3640 self=0x716401f8
| sysTid=6839 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1899029304
| state=S schedstat=( 1629483125 206446831 793 ) utm=150 stm=12 core=3
#00 pc 00021a90 /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+12)
#01 pc 0000f04c /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
#02 pc 0000f0ac /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
#03 pc 00055785 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmRelativeCondWait(pthread_cond_t*, pthread_mutex_t*, long long, int)+24)
#04 pc 000756cb /system/lib/libdvm.so
#05 pc 00057815 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#06 pc 0000d258 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#07 pc 0000d3f0 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

NATIVE THREADS:
"zygote" sysTid=6846 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
| state=S schedstat=( 267760 3741614 5 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0

"GL updater" sysTid=7480 nice=-10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
| state=S schedstat=( 14861196 12149217 394 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=0

----- end 6835 -----


----- pid 999 at 2014-08-02 05:42:34 -----
Cmd line: system_server

JNI: CheckJNI is off; workarounds are off; pins=5; globals=2142 (plus 322 weak)
```

The method of the class is this:

```
private Bitmap getPhotoUri(String idContact) {
        try {
            Cursor cur = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + idContact + " AND "
                            + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='"
                            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null,
                    null);
            if (cur != null) {
                if (!cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    return null; // no photo
                }
            } else {
                return null; // error in cursor process
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {
            Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(idContact));
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.withAppendedPath(person, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        } else {
             Uri my_contact_Uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(idContact));
             InputStream photo_stream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(), my_contact_Uri, true);
             BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(photo_stream);
             bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
             try {
                buf.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

The problem has been found on a phone that have Android 4.4. In many other situation, on other os version, the method works correctly.

Comment: Maybe the bitmap is too big for the phone?

Comment: The fact that it's a problem reading a file on 4.4 makes me wonder if its a problem with the SD card changes.

Comment: How i can i solve this problem? Maybe can i insert a try-catch to control that?

Comment: I'd try to figure out *why* it was printing a stack trace at the time the thread was suspended.  Does part of it show up in the log?

Comment: A user was using my app sent me this report of crash..

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who still has problems with this type of error this is what I concluded:

After a ton of searching and trying everything I could find on the web I have fixed it myself. I used **DDMS** to view the current threads that are running on my device, and saw that there was an **ASyncTask** which was running for a long time and never stopped.

It seems that it was accessing 'something' that the main thread was accessing and after a while of accessing that 'something', the two threads bumped causing an application hang which led to an ***ANR*** exception.

What I did is remove the **ASyncTask** and instead do this 'One-time' operation at the start of the app (when it initiates) that makes sure it will run once and never more.

I truly recommend to use **DDMS** to view the current threads as an ***ANR*** is usually caused by a synchronisation/concurrency issue.

Feel free to contact me privately if you get this error.

Comment: I too faced the same error, how do you get to know which process is going on for a long time and all and how to find which class because in my case i'm not using any `ASyncTask` in that particular class

Comment: @George Cloone-y can you please ellaborate it a bit more how you resolved this problem or can share your contact details so that we can have a short discussion?